# Hard to explain JavaScript issue about the scope of "this"

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the title, but it's really hard to put a title on this issue (feel free to suggest a better one).

My issue is best explained via this JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryLhcn4q/2/

```
CS = {};

CS.OverviewController = {
    foo: "bar",

    render: function() {
        console.log("Rendering. foo = " + this.foo);
    }    
};

CS.handleClick = function(callback) {
    console.log("handleClick");

    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
};

$("button").click(function(e) {
    CS.handleClick(CS.OverviewController.render);
});
```

If you click on the button, the console indicates that the value of `foo` is `undefined`. How can I have the correct scope of `this`, so that the console indicates `bar` as the value for `foo`?

Comment: See the third question of the fun quiz on the link provided by @BenFortune to know what happened!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
CS.handleClick(CS.OverviewController.render.bind(CS.OverviewController));
```

`.bind` defines the context of the function. Or in other words it sets its `this` object to something.

Your example doesn't work because you refer a function out of its context. The `this` points to the global scope (i.e. the `window` object). So:

```
window.foo = 'global';
$("button").click(function(e) {
    CS.handleClick(CS.OverviewController.render);
});
```

will output `global` -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryLhcn4q/6/)

Answer (score 0):

PFB the code, this will work

```
    CS = {};

CS.OverviewController = {
    foo: "foo",

    render: function() {
        console.log("rendering. foo = " + this.foo);
    }    
};

CS.handleClick = function(e, context, callback) {
    console.log("handleClick");

    if (callback) {
        context[callback]();
    }
};

$("button").click(function(e) {
    CS.handleClick(e, CS.OverviewController, 'render');
});
```

[JsFiddleUpdated](https://jsfiddle.net/ryLhcn4q/5/)

You can also use "apply" or "call"

Comment: You attached not updated JSFiddle link, check it please.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov thank you, i updated : )

Comment: Thank you for your answer Wishy! I prefer Krasimir's version though, you should check it out!

Comment: @Blackbird yep he gave a good one! i wanted to suggest call or apply but then i was thinking of from inside handleClick, didn think of using it in argument itself : )